# Compile errors in a test program with function pointers

Tags: c, compiler-errors, function-pointers

I've written a simple C program to learn usage of function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*workA) ( char *vA );
int (*workB) ( char *vB );

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char *strA = "Hello.";
    char *strB = "Bonjour.";

    int a = workA(strA);
    int b = workB(strB);

    printf("Return value of A = %d, B = %d.\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}

int (*workA)( char *vA )
{
    printf("A: %s\n", vA); // line 20

    return 'A';
}

int (*workB)( char *vB )
{
    printf("B: %s\n", vB); // line 27

    return 'B';
}
```

GCC complains:

```
test.c:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
test.c:27: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. Any comments will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`workA` and `workB` are pointers to two functions. You need to declare actual functions that will do the work, then assign them to your two pointers before you call them...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*workA) ( char *vA );
int (*workB) ( char *vB );

int workAFunction( char *vA )
{
    printf("A: %s\n", vA); // line 20

    return 'A';
}

int workBFunction( char *vB )
{
    printf("B: %s\n", vB); // line 27

    return 'B';
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char *strA = "Hello.";
    char *strB = "Bonjour.";

    workA = workAFunction;
    workB = workBFunction;

    int a = workA(strA);
    int b = workB(strB);

    printf("Return value of A = %d, B = %d.\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `int (*workA) ( char *vA )`, it means that *workA* is a pointer to a function that returns an int. `workA` is *not* a function.

Removing the parentheses around `*workA` and simply writing `int (*workA) ( char *vA )` makes `workA` a function returning a pointer to an int, as required.

The same goes for workB.

You can use this great program called [`cdecl`](http://cdecl.org/) to ease things up.

Comment: Thanks. "cdecl" is an awesome example.